Dependency injection with generic repository pattern
I recently wrote a program using the repository pattern to cover CRUD operations. Now, my question is how I can further optimize it and how I can integrate it with dependency injection.
So far, I've only managed to do it using an inelegant method (initializing services in a static class).
IBaseService interface:
namespace MyProject.DB.Services
{
    public interface IBaseServices<T>
    {
        Task CreateAsync(T entity);
        Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
        Task DeleteAsync(T entity);
        Task DeleteByIDAsync(int id);
        Task<T> GetByIDAsync(int id);
        Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync();
    }
}

BaseService class:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 
using System.CodeDom; 
using MyProject.DB.Entitys;

namespace MyProject.DB.Services
{
    public class BaseServices<T> : IBaseServices<T> where T : BaseModel
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public BaseServices(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            T t = _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.ID == entity.ID).First();

            if (t != null)
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
        {
            T t = _context.Set<T>().Find(entity);

            if (t != null)
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task DeleteByIDAsync(int id)
        {
            T t = _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.ID == id).First();

            if (t != null)
            {
                _context.Set<T>().Remove(t);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIDAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
        }
    }
}

Make service available for according class:
using MyProject.DB.Entitys;

namespace MyProject.DB.Services
{
    public class PriceServices : BaseServices<Price> 
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public PriceServices(DataContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}

To make these services available for all the needed classes, you have to initialize them by inheriting from the same class or interface:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProject.DB.Entitys
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}

DataContext (could be optimized too):
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyProject.DB.Entitys;

namespace MyProject.DB
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Vehicles;Integrated Security=True;");
        }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    }
}

Gross initialization of my services:
using MyProject.Business; 
using MyProject.DB.Entitys;

namespace MyProject.DB.Services
{
    public static class MyServices
    {
        public static readonly DataContext context = new DataContext();
        public static readonly IBaseServices<Car> carServices = new CarServices(context);
        public static readonly IBaseServices<Type> typeServices = new TypeServices(context);
        public static readonly IBaseServices<Price> priceServices = new PriceServices(context);
    }
}

I'd like to replace the static class, which I use to initialize the services with dependency injection, how can I do that?

With Dependency Injection we prefer 'composition over inheritance', but your PriceServices inherits from your BaseService<T> repository implementation. Instead, consider letting PriceServices depend on IBaseServices<Price>  by adding IBaseServices<Price> as constructor argument. By doing that, you'll be practicing DI, as the IBaseServices<Price> is injected into PriceServices's constructor.

So, in order to start with dependency injectio you need to configure your services with ServiceCollection class.
For EF DbContext there's already existing method AddDbContext which you can use.
For custom classes there are many options, depending on the lifetime you want to use, for example AddTransient.
Here's sample console app example with basic setup for dependency injection:
// Sample setup
public interface IInterface;
public class Concrete : IInterface;
public class DataContext : DbContext;

// Sample application
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
builder.ConfigureServices(servicesCollection =>
{
    servicesCollection.AddTransient<IInterface, Concrete>();
    // In your case it would be
    servicesCollection.AddTransient<BaseServices<Price>, PriceServices>();
    servicesCollection.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
});

var app = builder.Build();

var concrete = app.Services.GetService<IInterface>();

Console.WriteLine(concrete.GetType().Name);


As you are using c# and EF Core you will probably want to use microsofts official dependency injection framework (builtin in .NET). You can setup services like this:
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<DataContext>();

services.AddTransient<IBaseService<Car>, BaseService<Car>>();
services.AddTransient<IBaseService<Type>, BaseService<Type>>();
services.AddTransient<IBaseService<Price>, BaseService<Price>>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

Then you can use the service provider directly like this:
var carService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBaseService<Car>>();

Or if you define a constructor you can use the ActivatorUtilities and the ServiceProvider to .NET do the setup for you:
public class ServiceThatUsesAService
{
    public ServiceThatUsesAService(IBaseService<Car> carService)
    {
        /// ...
    }
}


var someService = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ServiceThatUsesAService>(serviceProvider);

You should have a look at the official docs about Dependency Injection or just search YouTube for tutorials.
Dependency Injection Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection
Also look up the Host Pattern to make your apps more streamlined with setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=hostbuilder. This is a little bit advanced but really worth it because it makes managing services and configs a lot easier.
Really have a look into these patterns, they make your life so much easier as a developer. I know because I have tried to invent this by myself: I have done exactly the same with a lot of static classes over multiple projects and layers and it really was a pain. If someone had shown me the dependency injection framework it would have solved me weeks of work and pain.
